# Save frames extracted from Deepstream pipeline to video using OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, nvidia-deepstream

I’m trying to save extracted frames from a Deepstream pipeline to video with OpenCV but all I end up with is a 9KB file.

This is my code (executed inside a probe function):

```
batch_meta = pyds.gst_buffer_get_nvds_batch_meta(hash(gst_buffer))
l_frame = batch_meta.frame_meta_list
frame_meta = pyds.NvDsFrameMeta.cast(l_frame.data)
frame = pyds.get_nvds_buf_surface(hash(gst_buffer), frame_meta.batch_id)
frame_copy = np.array(frame, copy=True, order='C')            
frame_copy = cv2.cvtColor(frame_copy, cv2.COLOR_RGBA2BGRA)
```

The above code is executed each time the probe function is invoked. Images are saved to a queue:

```
frame_buffer.put(frame_copy)
```

After the required number of frames has been pushed into the queue, I use below code to save the buffered frames to a video file:

```
codec = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('out.avi', codec, fps, (output_width, output_height))
out.write(frame_copy)                
total_frames = FRAME_RECORDING_THRESH 

while total_frames > 0:                
   frame = frame_buffer.get() 
   frame = cv2.resize(frame, (output_width, output_height), interpolation = cv2.INTER_LINEAR)  
   out.write(frame)
   total_frames -= 1
                
out.release()
```

Unfortunately the file produced is not a valid video file. Is there sth I am doing wrong in the above process? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

P.S. Just to test that the frames have been correctly stored inside the queue, if I attempt to save the frames as images inside the while loop:

```
cv2.imwrite(dest_folder + '/' + f'tmp{total_frames}.png', frame)
```

I get properly saved and valid png images.

P.S. 2 Frames have a resolution of `output_width, output_height` at the time they are buffered. Also, trying to do a `cv2.resize` before they are saved doesn't change anything.

Comment: if `frame` is different than `(output_width, output_height)` then you have to `resize()`  it - `writer` doesn't resize frames to size `(output_width, output_height)` but it skips frames which have different size - and finally you can get file with only header infromation but without frames.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't test it but common mistake is that people think than code

```
out = cv2.VideoWriter('out.avi', codec, fps, (output_width, output_height))
```

will automatically resize frames to size `(output_width, output_height)` but it is not true.

You have to manually resize frames.

If you don't do this then `Writer` will skip frames and you get broken file - without frames.

```
while total_frames > 0:                
   frame = frame_buffer.get() 

   frame = cv2(frame, (output_width, output_height))

   out.write(frame)
   total_frames -= 1
```

---

**EDIT:**

It seems problem can make image with transparent layer `A` -  `RGBA` - because video don't use `A`.

It needs to remove it.

You can convert with `cv2.COLOR_RGBA2BGR` instead of `cv2.COLOR_RGBA2BGRA`

```
frame_copy = cv2.cvtColor(frame_copy, cv2.COLOR_RGBA2BGR)
```

Or you can remove last layer from `numpy.array`

```
frame_copy = frame_copy[ : , : , :3 ]
```

Comment: The images, when buffered, have the same resolution to the one set in `cv2.VideoWriter`. Also, trying to resize them before saving makes no difference.

Comment: I can't test your code with your data so I have no idea what is the problem. I can only guess. Don't you get any error message when you run code? Did you tried to use `print()` to see if it runs `while`-loop? maybe `total_frames` is zero and it never run loop.

Comment: Yes, the loop executes. I even tried to save each frame as image, then load the image with `c2.imread` then save with `out.write` and I got a video file!

Comment: I can't reproduce you problem - so I can't help. And without error mesage I don't see what can makes problem.

Comment: do you imwrite/imread as `RGB` or `RGBA` ?  Video rather can't use `A` (transparency) - and maybe this makes problem to write it directly.

Comment: Hmm, the shape I get for the frame is 1920, 1080, 4. This is what I am using to write the video. Do you think this might be the problem?

Comment: I think I have to rewrite 
`frame_copy = np.array(frame, copy=True, order='C')`            
`frame_copy = cv2.cvtColor(frame_copy, cv2.COLOR_RGBA2BGRA)` some how in order to get rid of A? Is there a way to do this (some numpy operation maybe)?

Comment: there is `cv2.COLOR_RGBA2BGR` without `A` at the end so it should remove transparency. OR: every frame is `numpy.array` so you can get `frame[:,:,:]` to get only 3 layers - without layer `A`

Comment: Using `cv2.COLOR_RGBA2BGR` solved the issue, thanks! If you edit your answer to add this then I will mark it as an answer.